# Url mapping problems using Yii

Tags: url, yii, mapping

I have controller for static resources, for example images

```
class ResourceController extends Controller {

public function actionImage($fname) {
    $file = Yii::app() -> params['baseFilesPath'] . $fname;
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
        // header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fname);
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

And i have a url mapping for this controller:

```
urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'resources/<fname:\w+>' => 'resource/image',
            'product/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'catalog/product', 
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Yii generate rigth urls for this mapping:

```
/index.php/resources/bf81346e36131b5740bf96dc19b70ac0.jpeg
```

But controller doen`t called.

Can you help me? I think that my regexp is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is one *dot* in your `fname` parameter, and *dot* is not a ['word' character](http://www.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.escape.php) (`\w`), you should simply try the following rule :

```
'resources/<fname>' => 'resource/image',
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.url#using-named-parameters

> In case when ParamPattern is omitted, it means the parameter should
>   match any characters except the slash /